# window.open changed its location won't received a postMessage

Tags: javascript, web

(1) i have a script that opens a new window (2)New window can change its location/url for some redirection (3) I want to execute window.postMessage to the final redirection page of the popup window which will the parent window will received

```
<script>
 //open window
 //pops will change its url for some redirection
 var pops = window.open('http://est.com/test.php', 'Login with Test', "width=300px;heigth=500px;");

  window.addEventListener("message",function(e) {
    if (e.origin !== 'http://west.com') {
      return;
    }
   alert(e.data);
  },false);
  </script>


  <script>
   //code below is from other origin 'http://est.com/finalredirect.php'
  // 'http://est.com/finalredirect.php' is the final redirection page of the popup   window
  window.postMessage({'data': 'test'}, 'west.com');
  </script>
```

Or is there another work around for this?

Comment: Are you trying to post a message _to_ the second window, or _from_ the second window back to the original window?

Comment: pops  will bust if the popup re-navigates.

Comment: postMessage method will fail if protocols, domains and ports don't match on both sides.

Comment: Hi im trying to post from the second window. @hex464D49 is there another approach on it. Cause i was trying to have the pop up to be from the different web app then it will redirect to one of the pages of my web app and then postMessage.. so the first window can retrieve the postMessage of the last redirection of the popup